# Arena: How to count failures (or anything)?

Tags: arena-simulation

I would like to count the number of failures.

It is possible to create assignment statements in area e.g.:

ASSIGN:        Leaving Birth.NumberIn=Leaving Birth.NumberIn + 1:

I want to do this with when a failure happens.